# Getting push notifications to launch Chrome on desktop windows when not running

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, push-notification, background, progressive-web-apps

Would appreciated help on a gap in comprehension. Sending push notifications to Chrome running on a Windows 10 machine (tried on older Windows also) results in the notifications popping up only when the Chrome browser is open (similarly for installing the page as a PWA). On numerous sites and posts it says that Chrome can run a background process even when the browser is closed and still receive notifications that will kick off the browser or the PWA.

Have reviewed a number of posts from back in 2015/2016 which don't appear relevant based on current state of service workers, PWAs. Have also looked at the W3C spec and Chromium post on design and architecture which don't really seem to cover how the host OS (e.g., Windows) invokes the browser.

The Chrome browser is set to run in the background (setting->advanced->Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed) but on closing Chrome and looking at the running processes on the system, there does not seem to a Chrome background thread running (i.e., it does not seem that Chrome inherently runs some background process). Push notifications (e.g., sent via OneSignal) which result in the appropriate page being opened when Chrome is already open or the PWA receiving the notification (we are currently using GCM not FCM if that makes a difference) if it is open, do not seem to kick off the chrome browser if it is not already running. Otherwise the notifications are processed correctly.

From the google developer site and OneSignal documentation, etc, I had somewhat assumed (apparently incorrectly) that having a service worker for push notification would somehow create a background process environment.

So, the question is, what is required to keep Chrome running in the background to be able to receive the push notifications? Can it be done with a service worker? If the code is in a PWA is that different? Is a Chrome extension required? though having to create an extension would seem contrary to the point of creating the service workers and making the app a PWA.

I note also that it posts indicate that with Firefox this is not possible as Firefox completely exits on close with no background processes.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I think your question is fine as I'm trying to figure out the same thing. So far I can tell it's just not supported except someone keeps telling me that it is, so I'd like to find some evidence to show that it indeed does not. Mobile Chrome is a different story, but for Windows, it does appear to not work.